# Rendering arrows in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have the following HTML:

```html
<span class="HyperEditor ReadOnlyEditor">Game 1 of the Book of Why
$X \rightarrow A \rightarrow Y$ 
              $\searrow B$ 
</span>
```

which renders the following content on my browser:

[image]

Instead, I would like the following:

Are there any libraries that can help me accomplish what I want:

[image]

Comment: Go to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrows_(Unicode_block) and copy-paste whatever you need

Answer (score 3):

You could use the html entities for arrows as found here: https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/ and with some styling you woul dbe able to get the desired effect.

```html
<span class="HyperEditor ReadOnlyEditor">Game 1 of the Book of Why
$X &#8594; A &#8594; Y  &#8600; B 
</span>
```